# UISwitch decides if another UITableViewCell is editable

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, uiswitch

I have three custom table view cell in one section. First cell have a `UISwtich`. What I want is that when the `UISwitch` is `ON` then other two table view cell's `UITextField` are editable, otherwise not. 
Is it Possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a listener to your switch, check its state, and set editability of the two text fields from there:

```
// This goes into your viewDidLoad
sw.addTarget(self, action: Selector("stateChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

// This function does the work
func stateChanged(switchState: UISwitch) {
    if switchState.on {
        textField1.editable = true
        textField2.editable = true
    } else {
        textField1.editable = false
        textField2.editable = false
    }
}
```

I am assuming that `textField1` and `textField2` are outlets referencing the `UITextField`s in your two table cells.

Comment: It is a custom table view cell so it doesn't have viewDidLoad Method

Comment: @Dereck You can put it in the `viewDidLoad` of your table's view controller then.

Comment: It compiles but state changed doesn't get call, if i set the target in tableviewcontroller. However, it does get called when I set the target in the custom table cell class using the awakeFromNib() but the editing doesn't change.

Comment: I created the outlets of custometablecell class 1 and 2 in the customtableclass with the switch which is setting the target.

Comment: @Dereck This is very strange that when you set the listener from the tableviewcontroller's `viewDidLoad`. Your `viewDidLoad` did get called, right? Also the `stateChanged` function in this case should belong to the view controller, not the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can do the following:
1.add selector to your switch. 
2. The in the selector set a variable to 0 if switch is on & 1 if switch is OFF.
 3.Then call the reload data  method of tableview. 
4. Then in the cell for row method check if the switch is on using the variable that we have set and if switch is on set the cells textfields editable to true else false.